# How to turn on/off identity based authentication based on condition in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have used Identity based authentication in my ASP.NET MVC application, I want to turn on/off the authentication based on condition, I am trying to use custom authentication filter for that but its getting into infinite loop.

Below is the code for custom filter:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthentication(AuthenticationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(filterContext.HttpContext.Session["UserName"])))
        {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }

    public void OnAuthenticationChallenge(AuthenticationChallengeContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Result == null || filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult)
        {
            // Redirecting the user to the Login View of Account Controller  
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
            new RouteValueDictionary
            {
                 { "controller", "Account" },
                 { "action", "Login" }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: Sounds like your login page requires authentication so it's redirecting you to the login page... (repeating redirects).

Comment: @ErikPhilips No I there is no authentication attribute added for login controller